# Solve a matrix equation, given 2 matrixes

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

I'm facing a problem with solving the following equation:
$$
B^{-1}XA = -B^{-1}X+2E
$$
Where:
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}2&0\\0&3\end{bmatrix}, B = \begin{bmatrix}2&1\\2&2\end{bmatrix}
$$
And E is the appropriate identity matrix.

I tried multiple ways (by first calculating the inverse of B, multiplying it with A, adding $-B^{-1}X$ to both sides so I'd get $B^{-1}*X*A+B^{-1}X = 2E$, then after getting the inverse of B multiplied with A, I also added inverse of B to it, giving me $X(B^{-1}*A+B^{-1}) = 2E$. So I inverted the $(B^{-1}*A+B^{-1})$ to satisfy $A^{-1}*A = E, E*A = A$, which ended up with $X = 2E* (B^{-1}*A+B^{-1})^{-1}$

I might've done something wrong, maybe the calculations aren't allowed this way or something, anyhow the matrix which I got for A, didn't satisfy the equation.

Best regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
B^{-1}XA = -B^{-1}X+2I & \\ \implies& BB^{-1}XA = -BB^{-1}X+2B
& \\ \implies& XA=-X+2B
& \\ \implies& XA+X=2B
& \\ \implies & X(A+I)=2B
& \\ \implies & X(A+I)(A+I)^{-1}=2B(A+I)^{-1}
& \\ \implies & X=2B(A+I)^{-1}.
\end{align}

Comment: Sorry about the edit, was speaking about $A*I = A$ in my question yet edited it incorrectly in your post. I'll try to solve it and see if the X I get satisfies the first equation. Thank you!

Comment: And indeed it does. Thank you for answering! I kind-of messed up on the $2I * B$ part as it seems because I went on the same route before as well, after that I tried the route seen above. A big thank you mfl. :)

Comment: You're welcome.